# React button onClick renders three color, How to make that button?

Tags: reactjs, loops, button, colors, click

Hi I am trying to make a button in React which with each click gives a new color, this happens 3times and then it goes back to the default option. I tried using loops and everything but still it wasn't a success, Can anyone please help?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Button extends React.Component {   
  constructor(){
  super(); 
  this.state = {
      color_black: true,
    }
  }
  changeColor(){
          this.setState({color_black: !this.state.color_black})
  }
      render(){
      let bgColor = this.state.color_black ? this.props.color : this.props.color2
      return (
      <div>
          <button style={{backgroundColor: bgColor}} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>Button1</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
      render(){
      return (
      <div>
          <Button color="blue" color2="red" />
          
      </div>    
    )
  }
}
export default Button;
```

Comment: Why is there two button component?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of colours and keep that as a const. Then create a state to hold the index of the array, starting from 0. Then when u click the button, increment the index and use the array[index] as your color. When index is =3 reset to 0.